# Javascript mobile app crashing while open large document

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs

I created application with java script and it converted to native app and installed in android device.My application have download document option and camera. if i open that downloaded documents with in that application also taking pictures using camera then the application crashed automatically. I tried to find solution for this but i can't found anything.